# Check if a numpy array is lexicographically sorted

Tags: python, numpy

How do I check if a sequence of numpy arrays are lexicographically sorted?

```
>>> x = np.asarray([0, 0, 1, 1])
>>> y = np.asarray([0, 1, 0, 2])
>>> is_lex_sorted([x, y])
True

>>> x = np.asarray([100, 0, 1, 1])
>>> y = np.asarray([0, 1, 0, 2])
>>> is_lex_sorted([x, y])
False
```

Ideally this check would run in linear time and run at NumPy speeds.  Ideally also it would be able to return quickly when it first encounters a false result.

Comment: Your examples use only small nonnegative integers.  By any chance is that the use-case you are interested in, or are you looking for a completely general solution?

Comment: It's not a public function or indeed even NumPy, but in pandas' internals there's [`is_lexsorted`](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/fb7af6e257d5ca162487ea417eae675e3edbe271/pandas/_libs/algos.pyx#L99-L131) which is implemented is Cython and has the short-circuiting behaviour you specify: get it with `from pandas.algos import is_lexsorted` (pre 0.20.0). In NumPy you'll have to make several passes over one or more of the arrays, most probably.

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser I personally am only interested in unsigned integers in 0..n

Comment: @ajcr it might be good to submit your comment as an answer

Comment: Sure - I'll put something together now.

Comment: *"unsigned integers in 0..n"*  (Really pushing it now...)  By any chance is `n` less than 256, and is the number of columns always 4?  If so, you could put the data in an array with dtype `uint8`, and then use the `view()` method to view it as a one-dimensional array of big-endian 64 bit unsigned integers.  Then check if that view is sorted.

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser nice trick but sadly this is too specific for my needs.

Answer (score 3):

An implementation of `is_lexsorted` using pure-NumPy functions would almost certainly need to make several passes over one or more of the arrays (since NumPy functions are designed to operate on entire arrays in one go).

This means that writing the function in numba or Cython may be a better option if speed is a primary concern.

There's one such Cython function already implemented in pandas as [`is_lexsorted`](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/fb7af6e257d5ca162487ea417eae675e3edbe271/pandas/_libs/algos.pyx#L99-L131). This has the short-circuiting behaviour you specify and its running time is linear with the number of, and length of, arrays.

```
>>> from pandas.algos import is_lexsorted 
>>> x = np.asarray([0, 0, 1, 1])
>>> y = np.asarray([0, 1, 0, 2])
>>> is_lexsorted([x, y])
True
```

(For pandas 0.20.0+ use `from pandas.lib import is_lexsorted`.)

In pandas it's used to check if levels of MultiIndexes are sorted or not. However, beware, it's not in the public API and so could change in future.

Answer (score 2):

If `n` (the maxmimum integer in the arrays) and the number of columns are not too large, you can convert each row to an integer in a way that preserves the lexicographic ordering:

```
def is_lex_sorted(a):
    n = a.max() + 1
    v = (a*(n**np.arange(a.shape[1]-1, -1, -1))).sum(axis=1)
    return np.all(v[:-1] <= v[1:])
```

For example,

```
In [230]: x
Out[230]: 
array([[0, 0, 1],
       [0, 1, 2],
       [1, 0, 4],
       [1, 2, 1]])

In [231]: is_lex_sorted(x)
Out[231]: True

In [232]: y
Out[232]: 
array([[  0,   0,   1,  13],
       [  0,   1,   2,  30],
       [100,   0,   4,  10],
       [  1,  20,   1,  80]])

In [233]: is_lex_sorted(y)
Out[233]: False
```

Two problems:

- It will only work if the `n` and the number of columns are "small".  If they are not, the integers used in the calculation will overflow and the result will be wrong.
- It does not stop early.